# Suddenly Sublime shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, sublimetext

I'm using sublime text as my editor and when i'm writing code in HTML such as

```
 <div class="header"></div>
```

So there was a shortcut that i'm typing like that

```
.header
```

and then clicking <kbd>TAB</kbd> and it automatically make it, but suddenly it's not working, do you have any idea?

Comment: nope, sorry. You need to add more information - when did it stop working? What did you do between it working and not? Did you install/uninstall any plugins? Where did you get this functionality to begin with? Did you change those settings? Things happen for a reason, they don't just "suddenly" stop working.

Comment: I didn't do nothing.. suddenly it's stop working on each computer that i'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that.. still in HTML like i did before and it's not wroking anymore for me...
I tried also the sublime 3, both of them doesn't make the <kbd>TAB</kbd> shortcut for me.... ?

-- OK, i got it, i was needed to remove the EMMET packages and install it again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually in an HTML syntax file. You can tell what version you are in by looking in the bottom right corner:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wes.io](http://wes.io/Qz2B/content))</sub>

You can change it by either clicking it or opening the command pallet and typing `ssx html`

Comment: I know that.. still in HTML like i did before and it's not wroking anymore for me...
I tried also the sublime 3, both of them doesn't make the TAB shortcut for me.... ?